# Having route "/" show a different component depending on if user is authed

Tags: web-applications, reactjs, react-router

I want to have a route "/" that:

- if authed -> takes the user to the Home (Pages.Feed in the example below)
- if not authed -> takes the user to the Landing (Pages.Landing in the example below)

Basically, copy the behaviour for facebook.com or twitter.com.

I want to do this at the route level, and not to have a Component that makes the logic.

Right now I have:

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replaceState) {
  if (!store.getState().currentUser.nick) {
    replaceState({ nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }, '/landing');
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route component={Containers.App}>
      <Route component={Containers.LandingLayout}>
        <Route path="landing" component={Pages.Landing} />
        <Route path="login" component={Pages.LogIn} />
        <Route path="signup" component={Pages.SignUp} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/" component={Containers.AppLayout}>
        <IndexRoute component={Pages.Feed} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
        <Route path="about" component={Pages.About} />
        <Route path="help" component={Pages.Help} />
        <Route path=":nick" component={Pages.Profile} />
        <Route path=":nick/:slug" component={Pages.List} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('listlogs')
);
```

where "/" takes the user to his Home page (Pages.Feed) if authed, but redirects the user to "/landing" otherwise. Here, I need a specific route for the landing that I want to avoid. I'd like it to be "/".

Using:

```
component={authLogic ? Pages.Feed : Pages.Landing}
```

is not a solution. It would work initially, i.e the app would load the landing if the user is not logged in, and the feed page if the user is logged in. However, because the React router app is already rendered, the mapping to the component wouldn't work once the user had logged in in the former case or logged out in the latter. Would it make sense to somehow re-render the routing? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

The way you would do this with the router is to use either `getChildRoutes` on the route above your landing page, or to use `getComponent` on the route with the landing page.

These hooks give you the ability to run some logic, then call back with either the desired child routes or component(s).

For example, you could do:

```
<Route path="foo" getComponent={(_, cb) => cb(authed ? Page1 : Page2)} />
```

See https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.0-rc4/docs/guides/advanced/DynamicRouting.md for more details.

Comment: do you have any examples? I can't see how lazy loading will help me with this issue

Comment: I added an example to the answer.

Comment: can I use getComponent on an IndexRoute?

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense to do in the component to me, this is where you make other similar decisions about what to render based on app state.

```
const App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return authed ? <AppLayout/> : <Landing/>
  }
})
```